# Fantasy Football league stat tracker

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, google-sheets-filter

I am the commissioner of a small tabletop football league in Southern California. I'm currently using a league template spreadsheet to track individual player stats (TDs, passes, etc.), match results, and scheduling. What I am struggling to figure out is how to pull stats from each player's team roster tab to populate tables on the main page (player w/ most TDs, player w/ most passes, etc.). Another person designed the original sheet I'm using, and I'm not very good with this kind of stuff. Could one of you wonderful people [have a look](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MXuoZbC2ieOx0K_gZENDl5wS1gWGNEkBj2uLY0THne0/edit?usp=sharing)?

I have two sections in red brackets. On the first tab (League Tables), there is a section to highlight and rank the top 6 individual player's stats. On the second tab (Le Zards), another red bracket encloses where individual players' stats are recorded.

Is there a way to pull from each individual team roster (of which there are 6), select the 6 highest from the entire league, list them in a table and rank them?

I would really appreciate any help at all. I try to search for answers but I don't even know what I should be asking about.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on creating a dynamic query for each team, and then querying the the combined query results to get the top 6 players for the League table categories.

**Step#1: Team Queries**

- **Cell B7**:
  `=query({"ID","Name","Position","Miss Next Game","Deflect","Pass Comp","TD","Int","Cas","MVP","Team"})`

  - acts as a header.
  - includes a Team name
- **Row#8**

  - **Cell A8**: contains the name of the team sheet
  - **Cell B8**: `=query({indirect(address($B$5,$B$1,4,true,$A$8)&":"&address($B$6,$B$4,4,true))},"select Col1, Col2, Col3,Col16,Col17, Col18, Col19, Col20, Col21, Col22 where Col2 is not null  order by Col1")`

    - I used `indirect(address())` (with the column/row numbers in B1, B4, B5, B6 and the sheet name in A8) to dynamically create the sheet range, but there are other ways to do this
    - the "where" condition is important to return only those cells with a player name
    - the "sort order" also ensures that the player details are in the same order as the team sheets.
  - **Cell L8**: `=arrayformula(transpose(SPLIT(REPT($A$8&"♕",counta(indirect(address($B$5,$B$1+1,4,true,$A$8)&":"&address($B$6,$B$1+1,4,true)))),"♕")))`

    - Counts the number of player names on the team sheet, then creates an array consisting of that many instances of the team name in cell A8.
- **Row#21, 28, 34, etc**: wash and repeat

**Step#2: League Table Queries**
This is a series of queries of the combined team results based on the column number that matches the performance category, AND sorted in descending order, AND limited to 6 results

In this example, the queries are on the same page as the combined team results, but they would normally be entered on the League Table.

- **Sample: Touchdowns** - `=query({B7:L273},"select Col2,Col7, Col11 where Col2 is not null and Col7 >=1 order by Col7 desc limit 6")`

---

**Team Queries**

[image: team queries]

---

**League Table Performance**

[image: LeagueTable]